# Creating difficult/round section breaks with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make section breaks like these in picture below, but can't figure out, how to do this? is it possible to make this with borders and pseudoelements or it can be done only with svg?
[image]

Comment: SVG would be the best idea for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do lots of different shapes using CSS pseudo elements and borders: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Just a quick attempt on a shape like in your picture:

```css
hr {
  display:block;
  height:100px;
  background: #aaa;
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:none;
}

hr::before{
  content: '';
  background: white;
  width:200%;
  display:block;
  height:200px;
  position:absolute;
  top: -160px;
  left: -50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
hr::after{
  content: '';
  background: white;
  width:200%;
  display:block;
  height:200px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: -160px;
  left: -80%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <hr>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/sx4jk2jc/

```
<div class="round">des</div>

.round:before { content: " "; background: #ccc; width: 150%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 0% 100% 0% 50%; }
.round { background: #fff; height: 100vh; width: 100%; }
```

I just used the before pseudo selector, for having two colors as in your example you can use the after pseudo selector too. You should play with the border-radius values and width and height of the pseudo elements. Additionally if you need to change their position make the pseudo elements absolute position. Hope this helps!
Regards!